# An optimal solution that is also smooth

Tags: convex-optimization

I am given a vector **x**. My objective is to find an optimal **y** (minimize $||y-x||_2^2$). With the constraint $y(c) = a$ (a and c are known scalars).

$$\text{minimize}_y ||y-x||_2^2 \\ \text{subject to}\ \ y(c) = a $$

Further, I am confused about how to enforce a smoothness constraint. I am aware that in theory we add a regularization term to the objective function $ ||y-x|| + \lambda \bigtriangledown y $

I am trying to use CVX to achieve this. More info on CVX is Matlab Software for Convex Optimization (http://cvxr.com/cvx/)
How is it possible to have such a regularization?

Comment: what is CVX ( is it convex?) or a software program?

Comment: What does $y(c)$ mean when $y$ is a vector?

Comment: @satishramanathan CVX is a software package for solving convex optimization problems.

Comment: http://cvxr.com/cvx/. y is a vector and y(c) denote the cth component of the vector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The optimization variable is $y \in \mathbb R^N$.  Without a regularization term, the solution to the optimization problem written is the vector that agrees with $x$ except in the $c$th component, which is equal to $a$.  You can add a regularization term involving a (discrete) gradient of $y$ as you have mentioned.  One popular choice for a regularization term is
\begin{equation*}
r(y) = \sum_{i=1}^{N-1} |y_{i+1} - y_i|.
\end{equation*}
With this regularization term, you are solving a "total variation denoising" problem.

The optimization problem including this regularization term is
\begin{align}
\text{minimize} & \quad \|y - x\|_2^2 + \lambda \sum_{i=1}^{N-1} |y_{i+1} - y_i| \\
\text{subject to}& \quad y_c = a,
\end{align}
with variable $y \in \mathbb R^N$.

Comment: In order to achieve discrete difference, I need to use matrix multiplication (L*y)? L = [ 1 -1 0 ... 0 ; 0 1 -1 0 .. 0 ; ....]. My problem dimension is very large and I want to avoid this matrix multiplication. I know this can be achieved much more efficiently by use of a sparse matrix.

Where can I get information on more other techniques to achieve similar regularization?

Comment: I think CVX will allow you to express the regularization term in a way that doesn't involve matrix multiplication.  Something like sum(abs(y(2:end) - y(1:end-1))).  You could try reading section 6.3.3 of Boyd and Vandenberghe ([free online](http://stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/)).

Comment: That's right. I'd write that objective as `sum_square(y-x)+lambda*sum(abs(y(2:end)-y(1:end-1)))`.